# htaccess redirect loop on joomla

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I have all of my customers sites in a directory on my subdomain:

```
customers.example.com/sites/customer_name
```

I have rewritten the url from:

```
customers.example.com/sites/customer_name
```

to:

```
customers.example.com/customer_name
```

the problem is when i go to a joomla site, it makes a redirect loop, resulting in this address:
    http://customers.example.com/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/sites/customername//

my redirect works fine on static pages

Here is my current `.htaccess` file in the root of my domain:

EDIT:

found a better htaccess script which is faster, but stil gives me the same issue

```
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/$1/ [L]
```

Comment: I think that the last rule is cause.

Comment: Are you sure you want an extra slash at the end of your rule's target? `/sites/$1/` vs `/sites/$1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because joomla is probably doing routing, the two condition checks `!-f` and `!-d` will fail because joomla needs to route. Try changing the conditions to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/sites/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /sites/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change L to NL on second line.

Comment: Does not work. When i go to a joomla site, it still gives me the loop. Plus when i enter a static site, then it gives me error 500 internal server error